# Cannot find or register Proximity Beacons(ODYSSEY PROXIMITY BEACON)

Tags: android, eddystone, google-beacon-platform, eddystone-url

I am new to beacons and I have a pair of ODYSSEY PROXIMITY BEACON(Eddystone) and I tried to register it with Beacons Tool. But I cant find my beacons in this application. But I was able to find these beacons in similar other apps but there is no way to register it. Can anybody explain me why I cant find or register my beacons in Google Beacons Tool.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: It might be helpful if you post a screenshot of the "similar other apps" detecting this beacon, and mention which apps these are.

Comment: @davidgyoung Thankyou fro responding. Now I am able to register the beacon. I would like to know whether if we can remove the beacons from a specific project and can re register the same beacon with a new project

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only requirement for registering the beacon is working Eddystone UID (EID should work as well but that is different story). So are you sure the UID packets are configured and transmitted by the beacon?

Other apps can detect the beacon as a Bluetooth device. It does not mean UID packets are published. You should configure the beacon to publish UID packets. Maybe this guide https://www.ufobeacon.com/webdownloads/UFO-Beacons-Change-Eddystone-UID-ODY.pdf ?

You can always use the [Beacon Proximity API](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/register) directly, if Beacon Tools app is not working,

Answer (score 0):

You don't see the beacon in Google Beacons Tool if the beacon was registered for other project. You need to change UID Instance number to see this beacon again: https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/register